# Metadata is not setting in GCE from the node js library

Tags: node.js, google-compute-engine

I am trying to setMetadata in an VM instance, and for some reason the item data is not setting

I'm doing it through node js (https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/compute/latest/VM.html#setMetadata) and Have metadata that i also pass when i start up the instance, it is a powershell script [image]

```
    "userName": "xxxx",
    "modulus":mod,
    "exponent":exponent,
    "email": "xxxx@gmail.com",
    "expireOn": expiry
  }
  let dataForPass = {
    fingerprint: fingerprint,
    items: [{
      key: 'windows-keys',
      value: passwordGeneration,

    }]
  }
```

this is the data that im passing into the setMetadata function

```
vm.setMetadata(dataForPass, function(err, operation, apiResponse) {
   if (err){
     console.error(err)
     return
   }
    console.log(operation,apiResponse)
})
```

Im trying to follow this 
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/automate-pw-generation
and im trying to convert the py example to node. 
Thank you for reading !

Comment: Are you getting any error from your code?

Comment: No sir, there is no error

Comment: And you are not getting any response from the API? you should at least be getting a response with the status of the operation in your console.log